# for loop with if statement runs slow

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, optimization

I have a long data frame with approx 150k rows and two columns (A and B). I'm writing a code that in column "B" for a row "i", if the next 6 rows in column A == 1 then, B=1.

So far I managed to write a working code (see below). However, it is very slow to run, about 5min. Do you have any suggestions about how to make the code more efficient? Thank you!

```
df[j]['B'] = 0

for i in np.arange(0,len(df[j]['A'])-1, dtype=np.float64):
    try:
        if (df[j]['A'][i+1] == 1) & (df[j]['A'][i+2]==1) & (df[j]['A'][i+3]==1) & (df[j]['A'][i+4]==1) & (df[j]['A'][i+5]==1) & (df[j]['A'][i+6]==1) == True:
            df[j]['B'][i] = 1
    except:
        pass
```

I've tried to remove the try/except block but still no improvement, actually it is 1 second slower.

```
for i  in np.arange(0,len(WT_df[j]['ID10'])-7, dtype=np.float64):
    if (WT_df[j]['ID10'][i+1] == 1) & (WT_df[j]['ID10'][i+2]==1) & (WT_df[j]['ID10'][i+3]==1) & (WT_df[j]['ID10'][i+4]==1) & (WT_df[j]['ID10'][i+5]==1) & (WT_df[j]['ID10'][i+6]==1) == True:
        WT_df[j]['ID_on'][i] = 1
```

Best regards,
Luis

Comment: You can replace your if conditional statement to this `if all(df[j]['A'].iloc[i+1:i+6] == 1):`

Comment: @gajendragarg thanks for the suggestion. The code looks way better and its slightly faster (10s faster)

Comment: You can get rid of if. Just use ternary for the assignment. Does python support ternary?

Comment: @LGarcia, Try changing  `for loop` part with `for i in range(0, len(df[j]['A'])-1):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas direct indexing is slow (at least in loops). You can **vectorize the loop** to speed it up. Here is an untested example:

```py
column = WT_df[j]['ID10'].values
size = column.size-7
result = np.ones(size, dtype=bool)

for k in range(1, 7):
    result &= column[k:size+k] == 1

WT_df[j].loc[np.where(result)[0], 'ID_on'] = 1
```

Comment: thank you it improved the code a lot. The calculation time of the full code was approx 500s and now it's just around 25 seconds!